# shouldComponentUpdate() return false but component still re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an app where I have an `Overlay` component and a `Map` component rendering behind it just like this:

```
<div>
   {showOverlay && <Overlay />}
   <Map /> // this component should render only once
</div>
```

The overlay is shown to let the map load underneath but when I remove the `Overlay` (set showOverlay to false here) the `Map` component re-render.

At first I thought maybe a prop changed causing the re-render, so I tried to explicitly tell the `Map` component not to re-render by returning false in it's `shoudComponentUpdate()` method:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log("No, don't update please");
    return false;
  }
```

But the result is the same, the component get re-rendered when I close my overlay.

To make things even weirder, when the component re-render, `shouldComponentUpdate()` is not called (I don't get the `"No, don't update please"` log in the console).

What can cause my component to re-render then ?

Thanks !

Comment: The docs say that *Returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering when their state changes.* so if there are child components in the map they would still update

Comment: Probably, you are re-rendering the parent? not `Maps`?

Comment: @Prajwal No, the `Map` component get re-rendered (I put a console.log in it's render method)

Comment: @apokryfos There is no child in the `Map` component, it's render method return a single `div` element

Comment: Check whether you are re-rendering parent. If you do so, even `maps` will get rendered, along with `Overlay`.

Comment: @Prajwal By parent you mean the component rendering the `<Map />` ?

Comment: @ThéoChampion Yes.

Comment: @Prajwal Yes, this component get re-rendered, but this is normal behavior

Comment: It's possible that `Map` remounts when its parent renders. You can check this by logging `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @Oblosys Yes, It appears that the `Map` component is re-mounted, what can cause that ?

Comment: Most likely because you're creating a new `Map` object on each render. This can happen if you apply an HOC in the render function, or use a local function as a stateless functional component.

Comment: @Oblosys The `Map` component only render a MapBox map that is referenced using a ref (just like that https://gist.github.com/tristen/5c4b346ae38892f732504e6785d87057#file-map-js)

Comment: If `Map` is imported directly it should be stable and not the cause of the problem. It's also possible that any of the ancestors gets remounted (which causes all children to remount as well.) Maybe there's a `connect` in a `render` somewhere?

Comment: @Oblosys the parent does not re-mount and there is no redux code in my app

Comment: Hmm, hard to say what's going on then. If you can create a small example that shows the problem on https://stackblitz.com/fork/react I could have a look at it.

Comment: @Oblosys Was unable to reproduce the problem with a small example, everything works fine in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sapsps